# <SOLVED> Unity & MySQL | Scripts work in editor but not in build

Tags: c#, mysql, unity-game-engine

I have created a simple Unity application that uses MySQL. The app works perfectly in the Unity Editor, however when I build it for PC Standalone or Android, it does not work.

After checking the log files, the following exception has been thrown

> **PlatformNotSupportedException**: Operation is not supported on this platform.
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration..cctor () [0x00000] in <5bca8ad0d7cb4bf194403b342b8f0938>:0 
>   Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception.
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager..cctor () [0x0001e] in <5bca8ad0d7cb4bf194403b342b8f0938>:0 
>   Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () [0x002be] in <5bca8ad0d7cb4bf194403b342b8f0938>:0 
>     at Main.Start () [0x0008b] in <7257cb8e307a4c4d92671557aa30bf0e>:0 
>     at Main.Update () [0x0000d] in <7257cb8e307a4c4d92671557aa30bf0e>:0

How can MySQL not be supported on either of my platforms (both Android and PC Standalone) yet it works in Unity editor? Furthermore, I have recently created another game that also uses MySQL and works fine on all platforms. What could be the issue?

Feel free to ask me for code files, Unity files or whatever you think you need to help me solve the issue. Thank you!

Edit: Solved | just changed the API compatibility settings to .NET 4.x

Comment: Is this app just for you, or is it going to have users? Will they use their own database or yours? If the latter: you probably need a web API in between your app and the database for security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this because of API Compatibility Level, here are the references to similar problems:
[link 1](https://forum.unity.com/threads/system-platformnotsupportedexception.786155/)
[link 2](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2046)

API Compatibility Level can be found in:
**File > Build Settings > Player Settings > Player > Configuration**

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Because the mysql.data.dll work on windows and not on android.   create the folder plugins  into assets of your project and copy in it the mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar
it could work .....